# Is there a way to parse JSON data returned from a web service in actionscript without using as3corelib

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a method that needs to parse the JSON response. I looked around and people use JSON.decode() in the as3corelib. But I was wondering if there was another way to do this without having to install any other libraries like this (as3corelib). Like a native json method that comes with the actionscript libraries.

Answer (score 3):

[Take a look at the top level JSON class, available since Flash Player 11, AIR 3.0](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html).

> The JSON class lets applications import and export data using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

Why do you have a problem with using an external library?
There is no such thing as an installation required, you just download it.